# Converting Between Similar Classes in ArcObjects and WPF Runtime Libraries (C#)?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, wpf

There seems to be an "impedance mismatch" (if I can borrow the term) between similar classes in ArcObjects and the WPF runtime libraries. For example, there is a ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.Polyline in the WPF runtime and a ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPolyline (and corresponding PolylineClass) in ArcObjects.

I want to be able to do something like this (or at least similar):

```
var poly = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.Polyline();
var ipoly = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.PolylineClass();

// stuff happens

poly = ipoly;
```

Is there an easy way to convert between the two? Or am I going to have to write some deep copy methods?

Comment: usually I do something like IPoly = new PolyClass(), and then look the inheritance chain to see if I can cast IPoly into someother IObject.

Comment: Me too. But in this case, it appears there are no common ancestors since they are in different assemblies. And there is actually a Polyline class in ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry, but that doesn't match the one in ...Client...

Comment: I am wanting to know about this myself.  The link below did not help.  If anyone has a suggestion, please post.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This article looks like it might help: [Serializing JSON Geometry Objects between Silverlight, WPF and ArcObjects](http://weblogs.asp.net/albertpascual/archive/2009/04/06/serializing-json-geometry-objects-between-silverlight-wpf-and-arcobjects.aspx)